# How to change the loading clock in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

How can I replace the loading clock in Flex at the cursor to something like loading wheel in the middle of page instead of cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go along with Jonathon Dumaine's answer, here's an example of the `Spinner` class I use as a busy indicator in my apps. Just remember to call the `stop()` method when you first load it since it will use memory in your app if it's playing even when `visible` is set to false. You can call the `play()` method when you want it to start spinning again.

**Spinner.as**

```
package {
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.styles.CSSStyleDeclaration;
    import mx.styles.StyleManager;


    [Style(name="tickColor",type="uint",format="Color",inherit="no")]
    public class Spinner extends UIComponent {
        private static var STYLE_TICK_COLOR:String = "tickColor";
        private var tickColorChanged:Boolean;

        private static var classConstructed:Boolean = classConstruct();

         // Make sure we create the ticks the first time updateDisplayList is called
        private var creation:Boolean = true;


        private var fadeTimer:Timer;
        private var _isPlaying:Boolean;

        private var _numTicks:int = 12;
        private var numTicksChanged:Boolean;

        private var _size:Number = 30;
        private var sizeChanged:Boolean;

        private var _tickWidth:Number = 3;
        private var tickWidthChanged:Boolean;

        private var _speed:int = 1000;
        [Bindable] public var fadeSpeed:int = 600;

        public var autoPlay:Boolean = true;

        public function Spinner() {
            super();

            addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleCreationComplete);
            addEventListener(FlexEvent.REMOVE, handleUnloading)
        }


        private function handleCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void {
            removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleCreationComplete);
            if (autoPlay) {
                play();
            }
        }


        /**
         * Set the height and width based on the size of the spinner. This should be more robust, but oh well.
         */
        override protected function measure():void {
            super.measure();

            width = _size;
            height = _size;
        }


        /**
         * Override the updateDisplayList method
         */
         override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            if (tickColorChanged || numTicksChanged || sizeChanged || tickWidthChanged || creation) {
                creation = false;
                // Find out whether it's playing so we can restart it later if we need to
                var wasPlaying:Boolean = _isPlaying;

                // stop the spinning
                stop();

                // Remove all children
                for (var i:int = numChildren - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    removeChildAt(i);
                }

                // Re-create the children
                var radius:Number = size / 2;
                var angle:Number = 2 * Math.PI / _numTicks; // The angle between each tick
                var tickWidth:Number = (_tickWidth != -1) ? _tickWidth : size / 10;
                var tickColor:uint = getStyle(STYLE_TICK_COLOR);

                var currentAngle:Number = 0;
                for (var j:int = 0; j < _numTicks; j++) {

                    var xStart:Number = radius + Math.sin(currentAngle) * ((_numTicks + 2) * tickWidth / 2 / Math.PI);
                    var yStart:Number = radius - Math.cos(currentAngle) * ((_numTicks + 2) * tickWidth / 2 / Math.PI);
                    var xEnd:Number = radius + Math.sin(currentAngle) * (radius - tickWidth);
                    var yEnd:Number = radius - Math.cos(currentAngle) * (radius - tickWidth);

                    var t:Tick = new Tick(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd, tickWidth, tickColor);
                        t.alpha = 0.1;

                    this.addChild(t);

                    currentAngle += angle;
                }

                // Start the spinning again if it was playing when this function was called.
                if (wasPlaying) {
                    play();
                }

                tickColorChanged = false;
                numTicksChanged = false;
                sizeChanged = false;
                tickWidthChanged = false;
            }
        }


        private static function classConstruct():Boolean {
            if (!FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("Spinner")) {
                // If there is no CSS definition for StyledRectangle, 
                // then create one and set the default value.
                var newStyleDeclaration:CSSStyleDeclaration = new CSSStyleDeclaration();
                newStyleDeclaration.setStyle(STYLE_TICK_COLOR, 0x000000);
                FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.setStyleDeclaration("Spinner", newStyleDeclaration, true);
            }
            return true;
        }

        override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void {
            if (styleProp == STYLE_TICK_COLOR) {
                tickColorChanged = true;
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }


        /**
         * Begin the circular fading of the ticks.
         */
        public function play():void {
            if (! _isPlaying) {
                fadeTimer = new Timer(speed / _numTicks, 0);
                // addEventListener for the ticking going forward
                fadeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTicking);
                fadeTimer.start();
                _isPlaying = true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Start the Tick at each Timer.
         */
        public function handleTicking(e:TimerEvent):void {
                    var tickNum:int = int(fadeTimer.currentCount % _numTicks);

                    if (numChildren > tickNum) {
                        var tick:Tick = getChildAt(tickNum) as Tick;
                            tick.fade(fadeSpeed != 1 ? fadeSpeed : speed * 6 / 10);
                    }
        }

        /**
         * Start the Tick at each Timer.
         */
        public function handleUnloading(e:FlexEvent):void {
            stop();
            removeEventListener(FlexEvent.REMOVE, handleUnloading);
            trace("Removing "+this.uid.toString());
        }

        /**
         * Stop the spinning.
         */
        public function stop():void {
            if (fadeTimer != null && fadeTimer.running) {
                _isPlaying = false;
                fadeTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTicking);
                fadeTimer.stop();
            }
        }

        /**
         * The overall diameter of the spinner; also the height and width.
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function set size(value:Number):void {
            if (value != _size) {
                _size = value;
                sizeChanged = true;
                invalidateDisplayList();
                invalidateSize();
            }
        }

        public function get size():Number {
            return _size;
        }

        /**
         * The number of 'spokes' on the spinner.
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function set numTicks(value:int):void {
            if (value != _numTicks) {
                _numTicks = value;
                numTicksChanged = true;
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }

        public function get numTicks():int {
            return _numTicks;
        }

        /**
         * The width of the 'spokes' on the spinner.
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function set tickWidth(value:int):void {
            if (value != _tickWidth) {
                _tickWidth = value;
                tickWidthChanged = true;
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        }

        public function get tickWidth():int {
            return _tickWidth;
        }

        /**
         * The duration (in milliseconds) that it takes for the spinner to make one revolution.
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function set speed(value:int):void {
            if (value != _speed) {
                _speed = value;
                fadeTimer.stop();
                fadeTimer.delay = value / _numTicks;
                fadeTimer.start();
            }
        }

        public function get speed():int {
            return _speed;
        }


        public function get isPlaying():Boolean {
            return _isPlaying;
        }
    }
}
```

**Tick.as**

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import mx.effects.Fade;

    public class Tick extends Sprite {
        private var tickFade:Fade = new Fade(this);


        public function Tick(fromX:Number, fromY:Number, toX:Number, toY:Number, tickWidth:int, tickColor:uint) {
            this.graphics.lineStyle(tickWidth, tickColor, 1.0, false, "normal", "rounded");
            this.graphics.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
            this.graphics.lineTo(toX, toY);
        }


        public function fade(duration:Number):void {
            tickFade.alphaFrom = 1.0;
            tickFade.alphaTo = 0.1;
            tickFade.duration = duration;
            tickFade.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats very good. In flex 3 replace 'FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.getStyleDeclaration' with 'StyleManager.setStyleDeclaration'

Comment: You should give credit to Jake for making that control: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1219018

Comment: @Jonathan Dumaine, You are absolutely right! I was given that component by a coworker and didn't know where it originally came from, but certainly credit goes to where credit is due. Thanks to Jake Hawkes for the component and thanks to you for the link to the original!

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried the one above works great but seems to consume lots of memory for what's it's doing, did you try profiling it? also my main questions is how to disable the loading clock. I'm using Cairngorm and at some point it shows the loading the clock not sure how to auto disable so I can something like your spinner above

Comment: @Tam, This component can be very memory intensive. That's why I recommended calling the stop() method whenever the spinner isn't visible or active on the stage in my answer above. Definitely something to keep an eye on. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use this spinner as a cursor. I typically show it on screen instead.

Comment: @Jason Thanks.  Do you know how to automatically tell Flex not to show the clock loading Cursor?

Comment: Never mind I found out it was in:  <mx:RemoteObject ...
      showBusyCursor="false">

Answer (score 5):

I loathe that little clock. A clock on the mouse just tells the user that *something* is busy, but they don't know what. It is much better to display a progress indicator visually NEAR the thing that it is showing the progress of!

So, my solution is to enforce a ban on CursorManager, and instead supply your own progress indicator.

Example: A submit button in a form. You know that the submittal is asynchronous and it will take an indeterminate amount of time. So after the user clicks the button and the request is executed, display a little spinner to the direct right of the button. When the request is complete, hide the spinner. It's very sad to see a user who is worried that her actions did not accomplish anything--so give them a way of determining that your application is indeed functioning!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Do you know if there is a way to tell Flex not to use the loading clock. I'm using Cairngorm that at some point shows loading spinner when sending request to the server.

Comment: You could monkey-patch CursorManager and comment out showBusyCursor()'s body (not sure of the exact method name).

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the cursor rather than calling setBusyCursor on the CursorManager use http://www.igorcosta.com/flex3/doc/mx/managers/CursorManager.html#hideCursor() then just toggle the visibility of an overlay with your loading graphic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CursorManager.showCursor(); and CursorManager.removeBusyCursor(); to show and remove busy cursor.